# How can I redirect when someone enters www.subdomain.domain.com to subdomain.domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain

I have several websites that I use a subdomain as part of the main url.

subdomain.domain.com

When someone enters www.subdomain.domain.com they get an error, I want to redirect that to subdomain.domain.com.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `mod_rewrite` enabled:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule .* http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```